# Element Retaining Focus After Triggering Blur

Tags: jquery, blur, preventdefault

I have a span and a text input next to each other, named "one" and "two" respectively; with only one showing at a time.  When you double click "one", it becomes hidden while showing and focusing on "two".  When "two" is blurred, it hides and shows "one".  Easy enough, the problem manifests when I try to blur "two" when the enter key is pressed.  Here is what I have:

```
.bind({'blur keyup': (function(e){
  if(e.type === 'keyup' && e.keyCode !== 10 && e.keyCode !== 13) return;
  $([this,$(this).prev()]).toggle(); })
 })
```

When the enter key is pressed, the toggle occurs but fires again when you click anywhere.  So it seems blur fires, but "two" retains focus.  [Here is a fiddle has the two listeners separated (keyup and blur) as well as some extra to help highlight what's happening.](http://jsfiddle.net/F3R7w/)

I tried

- adding `e.preventDefault()`
- adding `return false` (before blur) --> Kills the rest of the function (as expected)
- adding `return false` (after blur) --> Disables the enter key (??) or after:

  - keyup: `(return function(e){` --> jQuery doesn't like this syntax
- Performing .toggle() in a different function --> No difference, unless:

  - `setTimeout` (even with time of 0) --> Issue goes away
- Using a different listener (key[down/press]) --> No difference
- Calling a separate function -> No difference

**Question:  How can I fix this?  The expected behavior is that *pressing the enter key yields the same action as blur*.**

Comment: Instead of forcing a blur in the keyup handler, you could just set the focus to another element

Comment: While that does work, I don't really have another input that I want to switch focus to.  It would be ideal if I could "focus" on the document itself or (preferably) find what's causing this behavior.

Comment: Actually this is quite interesting, if you don't hide the input, triggering blur works fine. The toggling of the input causes the issue!

Comment: I guess jQuery just wants to pick on me.

Comment: I tried with classes as well, and the problem persists. It'll be good when we figure this one out :)

Comment: Just for thoroughness-sake I set the display instead of using .toggle() -- No difference (not that I expected it to).

Comment: I'm aware `bind` accepts objects, but i didn't know you could have multiple events on the key portion of the object. That is to say wouldn't you need to `.bind({'blur':myFunc,'keyup':myFunc});` then define `myFunc`?

Comment: I didn't either until I read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432428/jquery-blur-and-the-enter-key).  However, in my fiddle, 'blur' and 'keyup' are separated to eliminate this confusion.

Comment: @gary: That question doesn't pass `{'x y':func}` it passes just `'x y'.func` (string and func and not an object). Either way, just saw your code and was curious.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure why, I was being killed by jQuery's blur method.  I was able to solve my problem by separating the two handlers and using JavaScript's native blur method.

```
keyup: (function(e){
  if(e.keyCode===10 || e.keyCode===13){ this.blur(); }
}),
blur: (function(){
  $([this,$(this).prev()]).toggle();
})
```

I'll leave this open until I or someone else can identify why jQuery's blur is behaving this way.